# Getting email addresses from Facebook *after* login

Tags: facebook, email, authentication, messaging

We have an integrated Facebook login that we build on the DotNetOpenAuth libraries some time ago. I'd sort of assumed that it would just keep working, but at some point the Facebook API changed and we aren't getting people's email address when they log in any more.

That's a separate problem, and I'm sure there are plenty of posts on that subject, and it's something I need to fix.

Another problem though is that one of our clients have just run a ticket ballot, and having had tens of thousands of people sign up and thousands of them be selected to win the chance to buy tickets, we now need to communicate with the winners to tell them they've won.

And we don't have their email addresses.

What we *do* have is their Facebook ID because that was saved with their login credentials.

Is there any way I can initiate communication with people - by retrieving an email address, or my sending a message via Facebook - if I *only* have their Facebook ID in a database?

Comment: You need their access token otherwise you can not get the email

Comment: I don't know how the API works, but if you have their Facebook ID, can you send them a message on this platform?

Comment: Did those users grant your app `email` permission when they logged in? If not – no way. Btw., not every user _has_ an email address on file with Facebook (f.e. if they signed up using their mobile) – so if you are doing any kind of competition that _needs_ an email address, you should implement an extra step to let users input it manually. (Too late now, but for next time …)